# Observe DOM mutation when Nodes are added/removed via chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, mutation-observers

I am writing a Chrome Plugin which needs to record all changes to the DOM. Also the ones made by the chrome devtools. 
I can use the MatationObeserver in a contentscript to get attribute changes but it is not possible to get inserted/removed Nodes by it done via the devtools. 
Anyone an idea?

Comment: You mean you are able to see mutations done via the scripts in the page but not when these mutations come from the dev tools?

Answer (score 3):

I think I missed "childList: true" as in :

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    for(var mutation in mutations){
        modificationList.push(mutation);
    }
});

observer.observe(document, {
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true,
    characterData: true,
    childList:true
});
```

But I still do not know why. I thought subtree should be enough.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli This was the OP answering the question, not adding more info.

Comment: Marcel, I added an answer to explain why you `subtree` works.

Answer (score 3):

As you pointed out in your own answer, you are missing `subtree: true`. I wanted to elaborate on why that is.

`MutationObserver` is focused on observing changes to individual nodes, and those changes come in 3 forms:

- 'attributes' applies when 'target' is an `Element` and emits mutation records for changes to attributes, e.g. `target.setAttribute`.
- 'characterData' applies when 'target' is a `Text` or `CDataSection` node and emits mutation records for changes to data, e.g. `node.textContent = ''` or `node.data = ''`.
- 'childList' applies when 'target' is a `Document` or `Element` and emits mutation records when its children are moved around, e.g. `node.appendChild` and such.

It seems that your issue is a misunderstanding of `childList`. It does *not* create records when children are mutated, it creates records when the top node's gets gains or loses children.

So then we get to `subtree`, which basically says `recursively watch`. That means that any changes to children of the `target` will also be recorded by this observer, not changes purely to the target.